# cannot find microsoft.office option in c# .net list

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating an application which requires a namespace inclusion of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
But when I write the following code I cannot find the 'office' option in the list.
using Microsoft.'office': this option is not present

Comment: You have office installed?

Comment: Yes. It works for another application. only the office option is not present

Comment: Did you add a reference to the same DLL as the other project has?

Comment: I cannot find the microsoft office reference. As when i type using microsoft.(here there is no option called office)

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly.

- Right click on your project
- click `add reference`
- find the reference in the built-in references list

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing the Primary Interop Assemblies.  PIA's get installed with Office if you choose a Complete installation or specify them during the installation process.  You can also download the PIA's you need from Microsoft.

**See Also**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: But it works fine with another application on same machine created by me

Comment: Check your references in the working application, and add the missing ones to your new project.